# Apache2 serves outdated and even deleted files

Tags: apache, php-5.5, libmemcache

I need help, my apache2 serves old versions of my files. What is stranger is even if I would delete the file the old file from the server-root but apache would still serve its old ramnant.

I realize am having a caching problem but I cant figure out how to fix it. My phpinfo image is as shown...[image]

Comment: What does this have to do with memcache ? Show us the http headers sent by one of the affected URLs or PHP pages if any

Comment: Are you using caching in httpd? What are the response headers on the deleted files?  Are you sure it's not your browsers own cache?

Comment: Memcache is unlikely to be an issue here, it works on a different level. What's more important is the browser's "Net" tab and the files' headers (usually in the developer tools), they will show whether the problem is browser side caching (which ist most likely the case!)